# Unicode query to Microsoft Server 2012 returning excess results

Tags: python, t-sql, unicode, odbc, pyodbc

I keep getting unexpected behaviour from our MSSQL server that I cannot explain.

Example:
The request

```
"""select * from vernacularname where (vernacularname = N'ᐱᓯᐢᑭᐤ')"""
```

returns the right result (id, vernacularname, language)

```
1 ᐱᓯᐢᑭᐤ cr
```

but also a shitload of other unicode names that I don't see how they are connected, like:

```
1 ܚܝܘܬܐ None
1 ᓂᕐᔪᑦ iu
1 እንስሳ ti
5 ፈንገስ am
6 ᐱᕈᖅᑐᖅ iu
6 ᐅᐲᑭᒋᑳᓇ cr
6 ގަސް dv
212 ᐱᔦᓰᐢ cr
212 ᏥᏍᏆ None
212 ወፍ am
212 བྱ། bo
216  None
216 ሓሽራ ti
359 འུ་འཐུང་སྲོག་ཆགས། bo
359 ጡት አጥቢ am
359 ᐱᓱᒃᑎ iu
360 རྟ་བླ། bo
459 ᎠᏓᏢᎢᎯ None
```

I'm using python2.6.5 and pyodbc to send the query. (pymssql did not process unicode queries at all)

Any clues about what went wrong are appreciated.
Thank you very much!

Christoph

Comment: python 3.1.2 shows the same behaviour.

Comment: Just noticed all results start with the same prefix, when converted to utf-16. (But I still haven't a clue how to fix it) :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the `Latin1_General_BIN` collation by adding a `COLLATE` in the `WHERE` condition to force comparison of the unicode value using a binary collation:

```
select *
from vernacularname 
where (vernacularname COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN = N'ᐱᓯᐢᑭᐤ')
```

This is a result of how SQL Server handles comparison of `WHERE` clause conditions, it's not specific to python or pyodbc. We can prove SQL Server is the culprit by reviewing differences in results between [original](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8118/8) and [updated](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8118/6) query.

See [Bart Duncan's reply here](http://www.databaseteam.org/1-ms-sql-server/554e0ac147d9cc78.htm) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for. I experimented with the collate command before, but didn't get it to work. Now everything is fine.